# Error when deploying app with "ng build --prod"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm using the command "ng build --prod" and get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null" in the production server but all works fine when I do the command "ng serve --prod". I'm tried to update all project packages but it still not work.

How can I solve this issue?

---

Angular CLI: 7.1.4

Node: 10.15.0

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 7.1.4

... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms

... http, language-service, platform-browser

... platform-browser-dynamic, router

### Package                            Versions

@angular-devkit/architect          0.11.4

@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.11.4

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.11.4

@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.11.4

@angular-devkit/core               7.1.4

@angular-devkit/schematics         7.1.4

@angular/cdk                       7.2.0

@angular/material                  7.2.0

@angular/material-moment-adapter   7.2.0

@ngtools/webpack                   7.1.4

@schematics/angular                7.1.4

@schematics/update                 0.11.4

rxjs                               6.3.3

typescript                         3.1.6

webpack                            4.23.1

Comment: where does the error occur? Also make sure it's not just an environment property that's missing in the prod config. :)

Comment: That error won't show in development server. You happened to use a temporary variable which was not declared or came to value 'null' at some instance. Take care of it and the build should be good.

Comment: @toskv error occurs in the server, it doesn't load any content and I get an error in the console. Yes, I have file environment.prod.ts which have config for production but it works correctly.

Comment: Have you tried `--environment prod` ?